# Access big size excel file with much complex formula by program

Tags: excel-formula, large-files

The trouble that bothoring me is: I can't find a good way to deal a big size excel file with some formula. i.e:
`=VLOOKUP($A8,items_item!$A:$Z,16,0)`
I have asked a question about my trouble some days before:[Phpexcel calculate formula across sheet page is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009641/phpexcel-calculate-formula-across-sheet-page-is-too-slow)

the method what i used before is phpExcel.what a pity! when the file is bigger and with much formula the memory usage and efficiency is so horribly!
Any body can give some good suggestion about deal big size excel file with formula.Any program language.Any advice will let me be much appreciated!

Additional:maybe the question I describe above is not clearly. what I did is provide a tool that deal some excel files provided by the users.and through the program get the data from excel(if it is formula,calculate it).then import the data in other storage.such as xml,db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to optimize Excel sheet. Normally in casual constructed Excel Sheet there is large space for improvement. For example, from the very one formula you posted i see you could restrict the table in VLOOKUP from $A:$Z to something smaller (this takes all the rows in the Sheet).

Comment: Yes,Mark Baker give the answer like you in the question: "Phpexcel calculate formula across sheet page is too slow". but what i did is a tool that deal excel files for others. I can't make sure everyone can optimize it's excel formula. What is bother me so much!

Comment: Thanks for your answer,Do you mean I should restrict the rows range in the formula? but the data set is increasing every day.:( .Can you any other suggestion. thank you again!

Comment: you can make it automatic (search for automatic range). There are a million of performance improvement that are possible. Usually the people who make excel file is not so much into programming. You could help them. Actually vlookup is quite fast, but you are searching in 1 million rows.

Comment: monobo,you can see the question,I add some more description.

Comment: There is not so much you can do, if you can't optimize the Sheets (that is where the maximum gain is). Maybe evaluate other technology, as Excel Services or SpreadsheetGear (I never used them so you must ask others).

Comment: thank you again for your answer! Maybe I should evaluate other technology.Java Excel API, Python xlrd ... It still bother me....

Answer (score 0):

Might be quicker to rely on the autoexpansion feature and LOOKUP in a Table:

`=VLOOKUP($A8,Table1[[Col1]:[Col16]],16,FALSE)`

where Table1 is the occupied portion of items_item!$A:$Z.

(Though I have not tested this.)

Comment: Sorry,I am not quite understand what you mean.Do you suggest I should optimize the formula?